# Dimension of Flow Polytope

Tags: polyhedra

**Problem**

I am reading the paper "Valid Linear Inequalities for Fixed Charge Problems" by Padberg *et. al.* (1985). In the paper, they consider the polytope

$$
P:=\text{conv}\left\{\begin{array}{l}x\in\{0,1\}^n\\y\in\mathbb{R}_+^n\end{array}:\begin{array}{l}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=d\\y_i\leqslant u_ix_i\text{ for }i=1,\dots,n\end{array}\right\}
$$

They state, without proof or reference, that under the assumptions

1. $\sum_{j\neq i}u_j>d$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$
2. $0<u_i\leqslant d$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$

that $\text{dim}(P)=2n-1$. I am attempting to prove this claim.

**Attempted Solution**

We have that

$$
P\subseteq\left\{\begin{array}{l}x\in\mathbb{R}^n_+\\y\in\mathbb{R}^n_+\end{array}:\sum_{i=1}^ny_i=d\right\}
$$

that is, $P$ is a subset of a polytope defined by rank-one equality-constraints. Thus $\text{dim}(P)\leqslant2n-1$.

In order to show that this holds with equality, we may either:

1. Construct a set of $2n$ affinely independent points in $P$, or
2. Suppose that every point in $P$ satisfies $$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\beta_iy_i=\delta$$ and show that this constraint is a scalar multiple of $\sum y_i=d$.

I haven't been able to do either of these. Any tips or references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the second technique: Namely, assume there is some equation
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i + \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i y_i = \delta,$$ 
valid for all $(x,y) \in P$, and let's show that this can only be a multiple of 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n y_i = d.$$

First, if we set $x_i=1$ for all $i$, we obtain the equation
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i y_i = \delta - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i.$$

For this choice of $x$, the set of feasible $y$ is exactly the intersection between the hyperrectangle $\prod_{i=1}^n [0, u_i]$ and the equality $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = d$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^n u_i > d$, this intersection is $n-1$ dimensional, and so the only linear constraint satisfied by all $y$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = d$. Hence, $\beta_i = \beta$ and $\delta = \beta d + \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i$. Rewriting our inequality we must have
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i  + \beta\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = \beta d + \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i,$$
or equivalently
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i.$$
But the condition $\sum_{i\neq j} u_i > d$, implies that there are feasible points for which $x_i = 0$, and $x_j = 1$ for all $j \neq i$, each of these implies that $\alpha_i=0$, and we have recovered the equality
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n y_i  = d.$$

Comment: In particular, this seems like a proof about the LP relaxation rather than the convex hull.

Comment: You are right, I was assuming the relaxation was contained in the convex hull, which is not true.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I'm a little confused on the existence of the $n-1$ dimensional set. We assert that the only linear constraint satisfied is sum(y)=d...but isn't that what we're trying to prove?

Comment: Well in this case it is much easier: Taking $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n u_i = d$, the point $y  = \lambda u$ is in the interior of the hyperrectangle, and so it is free to move on the hyperplane.

Comment: I don't think I follow. The proof asserts that $\sum y_i=d$ is the *only* linear constraint satisfied by all $y$. How do we know there can't be another?

Comment: By the argument on my comment above, the dimension is exactly $n-1$, and having another would mean the dimension is at most $n-2$.